# How do I solve this error: include files are nested too deeply

Tags: c++, include

Should I put also my headers, and not only the classes inside the ifndef, define etc?

For example I have, this is just an example of code. Now, my question is, should I put the #include "myfile.h" in the ifndef, or should it stay outside?

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "myfile.h"
   #ifndef ANOTHERFILE_H
   #define ANOTHERFILE_H

   struct node 
   {
    int val;
    node*next;
   }
   #endif //ANOTHERFILE_H
```

Comment: Your header guards should always be the very first thing in your file.

Comment: so every include has to put after the ifndef? even the include of the libraries?

Comment: Yes, all includes should be after your header guard.

Comment: Technically, if all of your headers are well-behaved and only includes are outside of guards, then it should be fine. But it's much safer to not rely on that and always wrap everything in include guards.

Comment: The header guards are to "prevent" multiple includes and including the includes outside the header guards defeats that purpose.

Comment: Also, avoid including headers from other headers when possible. Doing so slows down compilation.